# How do i create video from images with any slideshow effects(like fadein fadeout,crossfade,slides) using ffmpeg in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to create slideshow from bunch of images with the effects like fade-in fade-out, crossfade, slide from right to left, zoom-in zoom-out or any other slideshow effects and i want to create a video as a output from those images.

I have also tried with below FFMPEG command but it seems that it will work for only images having same resolution for different different resolution it doesn't.

> String fourImage ="ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 3 -i /sdcard/videokit/one.jpg
>   -loop 1 -t 3 -i /sdcard/videokit/two.jpg -loop 1 -t 3 -i /sdcard/videokit/three.jpg -loop 1 -t 3 -i /sdcard/videokit/four.jpg
>   -filter_complex [0:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v0];[1:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v1];[2:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v2];[3:v]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v3];[v0][v1][v2][v3]concat=n=4:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]
>   -map [v] -preset ultrafast /sdcard/videokit/fourImageSecond.mp4";

And also look at [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg) as i want to create same effects but it works for same resolution image only.

So my question is, how can I create video from images with slideshow effects using ffmpeg ?

Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: so what is the problem with image re-scaling before running `ffmpeg`?

Comment: @pskink Thanks, thing is that i have 10 to 12 image and want create video for the same so it can better if ffmpeg cammand will works without re-scaling all the images.

Comment: The concat filter requires all inputs to be same resolution.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to make the same size file then you have  to add effect

"[0:v]scale=1024x576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, setdar=16/9,pad=1024:576:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0];" +
"[1:v]scale=1024x576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, setdar=16/9,pad=1024:576:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1];" +
"[2:v]scale=1024x576:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease, setdar=16/9,pad=1024:576:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2];" +
"[v0]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v0];" +
"[v1]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v1];" +
"[v2]trim=duration=3,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=2.5:d=0.5[v2];" +
"[v0][v1][v2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v]", "-map", "[v]", "-preset",
strong text  "ultrafast", pathsavaing};

Answer (score 0):

As [official wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) says: ***All images in a series need to be the same size and format.***

You need to resize all images you have using below code:

```
Bitmap yourBitmap;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

or:

```
resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap,(int)(yourBitmap.getWidth()*0.8), (int)(yourBitmap.getHeight()*0.8), true);
```

After this step is completed read [this repository](https://github.com/jdpxiaoming/Android-FFmpeg-Images-Video).

Good luck :)